# Two questions about `Infinity`

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, built-in-symbols

These are 2 small questions about `Infinity`. They are not related each other.

Q1)

```
  In[1]  Level[{1, 2, 3}, {Infinity, 3.14}]
  Out[1]  {}
```

For expression `Level[SomeList, {arg1,arg2]]`, note that `arg1,arg2` should be integers or Infinity or -Infinity. If not, it is meant to produce an error message. But  expression of following type `Level[SomeList, {Infinity,arg2]]` does not produce any error message.

Q2) I think `Infinity^Infinity` should be `Infinity`, not `ComplexInfinity`.

```
In[2]  Infinity^Infinity
Out[2]  ComplexInfinity
```

I think these are two small bugs.

Comment: Your `Level` statement says start and infinity and go to 3.14. However, your expression does not have a level at infinity and it seems `Level` short circuits there for performance and returns the empty list since there is nothing further to evaluate.

Comment: In `ComplexInfinity` documentation you will see it is `DirectedInfinity`.

Comment: `FullForm /@ {\[Infinity], -\[Infinity], ComplexInfinity}`

Comment: About Q2) Thank you for DirectiedInfinity[..], so DirectiedInfinity[1] means that something is on the positive real line and getting farther away from the origin. Then, if x, y is on the positive real line and getting farther away from the origin, x^y is on the positive real line and getting farther away from the origin... so the answer is still Infinity(=DirectedInfinity[1]).

Comment: Please don't add [bugs] tag unless the community or WRI confirms it. Also, please avoid asking multiple distinct questions in one post.

Comment: OK, I will keep it in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that `DirectedInfinity[1]` indicates a real value going off to infinity in "the direction of `1`," as stated in the OP.  Consider

```
Limit[z + I, z -> Infinity]
(*  DirectedInfinity[1]  *)
```

This seems right to me that the direction of the infinity is the same as the direction of the positive real axis (see below); but the function approaching infinity, `z + I`, is not real.

Consider also the following:

```
Limit[(z + I)^z, z -> Infinity] // FullSimplify
(*  DirectedInfinity[E^I]  *)
```

The limit has the form `Infinity^Infinity`, but the result is not `DirectedInfinity[1]`. So there is at least an argument that `Infinity^Infinity` is not always `Infinity`.

The documentation makes two statements:

> 1. `DirectedInfinity[z]`
>    represents an infinite numerical quantity that is a positive real multiple of the complex number `z`.
> 2. You can think of `DirectedInfinity[z]` as representing a point in the complex plane reached by starting at the origin and going an infinite distance in the direction of the point `z`.

Neither makes much sense in terms of the standard field of complex numbers.

What we can say is that `Limit[f[z], z -> Infinity] == DirectedInfinity[t]` if (1) the limit of `Abs[f[z]]` goes to infinity and (2) the limit of `Arg[f[z]]` exists and equals `Arg[t]`.

The other common use of directed infinities, both in mathematics and in Mathematica, is in limits of integration. A limit such as $\omega\infty$ in $\int_a^{\omega\infty} f(z), dz$ indicates a path like $a + \omega t$, $0 \le t < \infty$.  This seems consistent with the limit property in that the limit of $\omega t$ is $\omega\infty$.

It is not clear that these constitute "the definition" of `DirectedInfinity[z]`. There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_infinity) on directed infinity, which adds a little to [a *MathWorld* article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectedInfinity.html) that repeats the first definition above, which I indicated was unsatisfactory.

*Addendum*

One can create an extension of the complex plane to include a circle at infinity. We start with a hemisphere,
$$a^2+b^2+(c-1)^2=1,\ c \le 1 \,,$$
where $c = 1$ on the hemisphere is the "circle at infinity" and the rest of the hemisphere $c < 1$, the "finite part," corresponds to the complex plane as follows:

The projection from $(0,0,1)$ onto the plane $c=0$ gives the correspondence between $x+iy$ in the plane and $(a,b,c)$ on the hemisphere.  The projection induces a metric on the finite part of the hemisphere, and the distance from a point on the circle at infinity to any other point on the hemisphere is infinite.  The points on the circle at infinity represent the "directed infinities." An "open neighborhood" of a directed infinity $P$ consists of the union of $\{P\}$ and an open segment of the hemisphere contained between two vertical planes passing through $P$ or intersections such a set with open balls containing $P$.  Such a model seems consistent with how `DirectedInfinity[z]` works.

Comment: `Limit[f[z], z -> Infinity] == DirectedInfinity[t]` if (1) the limit of `Abs[f[z]]` goes to infinity and (2) the limit of `Arg[f[z]]` exists and equals `Arg[t]`. <- Main point!

Answer (score -3):

The commands

```
Limit[x^x, x -> Infinity, Direction -> "FromBelow"] // FullForm
```

and

```
Limit[x^x^2, x -> Infinity, Direction -> "FromBelow"] // FullForm
```

and similar commands
produce the desired and correct result `DirectedInfinity[1]`
. Since `Infinity` is not a complex number as well as a real number(`Infinity \[Element] Complexes` returns `False`), `Infinity^Infinity` has no sense in traditional math and the result of `Infinity^Infinity` is know how of Mathematica developers.

Addition. In fact, `DirectedInfinity[1]` is not a math notion.  E.g. see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Limit) for accurate definitions.

Comment: (-1) Again, you mistake some single mathematical interpretation with the semantics of a computer algebra system. Do not conflate them.  BTW, in calculus books, one finds $\infty^\infty$. I would call such books "traditional."

Comment: @MichaelE2:  1. "The semantics of a computer algebra system" should be in accordance with math. 2. The notation $\infty^\infty$ in some textbooks means $f(x)^{g(x)}$, where the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ approach infinity (see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Limit) for accurate definitions ).